# Multiple Seek bars for videoJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am using videojs in my ReactJS application. I am showing markers on seek bar of videojs. Is it possible to have multiple seek bars out side video js so that I can control each seek bar separately and play video from any of them. If yes, then how to show multiple  seekbars? Is there any library already available?